# How to use a different compiler for single recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am building a yocto image for a multicore MCU (A7 + M4). The U-Boot and Linux run on A7. M4 is used for some real time operations.

Currently I am building the M4 part (cmake project) first and bitbake only adds the binary file to the image. What I want to do is to integrate the M4 build into the yocto build process. For this I need to specify a different compiler for the M4 recipe but I can't find any way to do it.

After reading yocto manual I think that writing custom do_compile method should work. But I guess there should be some way to use the existing cmake builder.

Comment: Basically the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089677/best-practice-for-building-firmware-using-yocto/

Answer (score 0):

I think the multiconfig feature is the one you want, as long as both variants have their own MACHINE definition:
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#dev-building-images-for-multiple-targets-using-multiple-configurations